# Why is Prettier adding this semicolon when I cast something with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, prettier

I'm using Typescript and Prettier and every time I cast something in the first line of the function Prettier puts a semicolon as a first character.

Why? It seems unnecessary. Am I wrong?

I read the [Rationale](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#semicolons) but still I cannot understand why we need to put the first semicolon there.

**Prettier 2.2.1**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAzArlMMCW0AEcAHgIYC2ADgDZwAUAlPsADpS0wAWOAzvibwFkAngBUhFOPQB0ZOJwgATBvgD0K-Om5wa3XlrI5IVAhzgAnOKwDctVH14koQ6UPwBefKldr8nOPn1DCGMofFMLfB58CABrVgsYdDNQ1FYAXxAAGhAIClxobmRQEjMzCAB3AAUShEKUEipykiFC7IAjMxIwGLkAZQounCgAc2QYM3Q4bLgyNrgFBXmAGUdh9BJhuAAxCDMyEhhcEeQQEnQYCCyQDhgyKgB1LnhuAbA4XtqcXAA3L6ETsC6K5DLRmGCVTrDfbIVANLTZABW3CIACFOt0+uQ4EshnAYXCpiAkURekNhjQAIroCDwfFUeEgAZmUEnGDiODcMBmHB5K4Ubmwe44BScZAADgADNl+RAtPdOhQTvyOeZvnjsgBHanwCG5OqnbgAWigcHm8yuFi1OAsEI20KQsPphMCdIZ3DJlO1eIdBOyMBIbSFIo4yAATH7OjgqGSAMIQMj2kAcgCsV00cBEAbqjoZ30mAEkoItYL0uTyYABBIu9Nk0V1wNJpIA)

```sh
--parser typescript
--no-semi
```

**Input:**

```
function example() {
(this as MyType).method() // useless semicolon will be placed here
;(f as any).y = fy // the semicolon here is ok
return f
}
```

**Output:**

```
function example() {
  ;(this as MyType).method() // useless semicolon here
  ;(f as any).y = fy // the semicolon here is ok
  return f
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

The first semicolon must not be put.

I opened [an issue on the Prettier repo](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10568) but they suggested I ask here.

*****UPDATE:**

If I use prettier defaults I have issues too, see this example:

**Prettier 2.2.1**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#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)

```sh
--parser typescript
```

**Input:**

```
export function inputSelect(e: MouseEvent): void {
    console.log("Test this")
    (e.target as HTMLInputElement)?.select();
}
```

**Output:**

```
export function inputSelect(e: MouseEvent): void {
  console
    .log("Test this")(e.target as HTMLInputElement)
    ?.select();
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

It should put the semicolon at the end of the `console.log()`.

Comment: It says why in that doc you link: *"It makes the line independent of other lines so you can move and add lines without having to think about ASI rules."* If you *did* insert a line before, the parentheses could get interpreted as *invoking* the result of the previous line. There is an example of this (with brackets not parentheses) in that documentation too.

Comment: Ok, but there is an issue also with Prettier defaults. I updated the question.

Comment: That's not an issue with Prettier defaults, it's an issue with your code. **You** need to add a semicolon there, because ASI won't. Prettier formats the code you've written, the problem is that code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I learned something today.

Comment: yes just like (function() {})() is a way to run a function JavaScript ASI assumes ()() means you want to create a function -- for all it (ASI) knows console.log() is generating a function and expecting e.target as its input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: I have the same issue. did you find solution?